# Location of resources regardless of the url (.htaccess url rewrite)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I recently started with .htaccess url rewrite and currently I'm facing a problem.

My folder architecture is like this:

- index.php
- .htaccess
- images/
- css/
- js/
- functions/

My website loads all pages by doing

```
index.php?page=register
```

where my pages are located in the functions map.

The problem is that when I put this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^register/?$ index.php?page=register [NC,L] # Handle login page request
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=profile&member_id=$1 [NC,L] # Handle profile page request
```

When I navigate to

```
<website>/register/
```

my CSS file is located at

```
../css/style.css
```

but when I navigate to

```
<website>/profile/1/
```

my css file is located at

```
../../css/custom.css
```

How do I make sure the page always loads my file from

```
css/custom.css
```

Is there maybe a variable that mentions the location of index.php? So that I can do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= $variable ?>/css/custom.css" />
```

I'm using XAMPP(latest version) on Windows and the website will be released on a Linux based webserver.

If you need more information about my implementation that I can't think off right now, I will share it.

Comment: Modify the .htaccess to redirect all requests for css to your css directory.  I think you'll need to add a RewriteCond as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to fix this problem:

1. Use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
2. You can also try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I like this solution since it requires only 1 line to edit if you move the folder.

Answer (score 1):

If your site is located in the basedir e.g. `http://example.com/` then just do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/custom.css" />
```

If it is located in a subdir like `http://example.com/mysite/` then you have to add it to your path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mysite/css/custom.css" />
```

You should add the following to your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This will "ignore" rewrite rules if a file exists, so that your css will be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Works like a charm. I prefer anubhava's answer since my folder is in a subdir and the usage of <base href="/" /> only requires one line to edit. Still thanks a lot for helping me out.